# Which method of adding items to the ASP.NET Dictionary class is more efficient?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, dictionary

I'm converting a comma separated list of strings into a dictionary using C# in ASP.NET (by omitting any duplicates):

```
string str = "1,2, 4, 2, 4, item 3,item2, item 3"; //Just a random string for the sake of this example
```

and I was wondering which method is more efficient?

1 - Using try/catch block:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

string[] strs = str.Split(',');
foreach (string s in strs)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
        try
        {
            string s2 = s.Trim();
            dic.Add(s2, s2);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

2 - Or using ContainsKey() method:

```
string[] strs = str.Split(',');
foreach (string s in strs)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
        string s2 = s.Trim();
        if (!dic.ContainsKey(s2))
            dic.Add(s2, s2);
    }
}
```

**EDIT.** Thank you everyone who participated!

A very interesting find. If you look at the answer provided by dtb below, he proposed two methods of using hashSet. I'll dub them over here:

Method 1:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(from s in str.Split(',')
                           where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)
                           select s.Trim());
```

Method 2:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (string s in str.Split(','))
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
     {
         hashSet.Add(s.Trim());
     }
}
```

I asked him which method is faster performance-wise, and interestingly enough, method 2 is faster. Here's the timing done using the Stopwatch class by running each method in a Release build for 1,000,000 times in a loop:

```
Method 1: 1,440 ms average
Method 2: 1,124 ms average
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need a set and not a dictionary, I recommend you use the [HashSet<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

> *HashSet<T> Class*
>
> Represents a set of values.
>
> A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order.

---

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(from s in str.Split(',')
                                  where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)
                                  select s.Trim());
```

or equally

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (string s in str.Split(','))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
        hashSet.Add(s.Trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a correct answer. I also learned something about HashSets. I'm not really familiar with what you added inside the HashSet() part though. Is it more efficient than writing it out like I did?

Comment: @ahmd0: Yes, it's more efficient in terms of number of words and readability, but not in terms of performance.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Thanks. Performance would be my #1 priority. So how would you write this with performance in mind?

Comment: Thanks. I'm still curious. Do you guys know, which method posted by dtb above would be more efficient (performance wise)?

Comment: Use a profiler and find out. I guess there's not much difference between the two versions. If you're not familiar with LINQ, I'd go with the second version.

Comment: Just use the [Stopwatch Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) and compare the time the two versions take. Execute both versions several thousand times when measuring, compile for *Release* and run without debugger to get meaningful results.

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like you need a dictionary: a simple LINQ expression should give you a list of items with no duplicates:

```
var res = str
    .Split(',')
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s))
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

If you insist on having a dictionary, you can use `ToDictionary` instead:

```
var res = str
    .Split(',')
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s))
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    .Distinct()
    .ToDictionary(s=>s, s=>s);
```

Using `try/catch` in the normal program flow is strongly discouraged, because it hides your intent: exceptions in C# are reserved for, well, exceptional situations, not regular things that you can safely trap with an `if / then / else` condition.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, although your method doesn't trim the values like I showed.

Comment: @ahmd0 That's a relatively easy fix - please see the edit. In general, LINQ gives you a lot of flexibility at deciding what to filter out from your initial set.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, what is better in my case List or HashSet? I'm talking only performance wise.

Comment: @ahmd0 It depends *entirely* on what you plan to do with it afterwards. If you need to enumerate it once, e.g. in a loop, and forget about it, you can drop `ToList` at the end; if you need to repeatedly iterate over the *entire* set over and over again, then the `List` is better; if you need to repeatedly check for presence or absence of specific items, `HashSet` wins hands down. So it all depends on your needs.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the expalantion.

Comment: It still keeps all the untrimmed entries... But even if I trim them, the list still contains duplicates, so to avoid those it seems like my only choice is to use HashSet like was explained above...

Comment: @ahmd0 I added trimming, check it out.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my original post. It seems like I'm sticking with HashSet and not a LINQ version because it's slower.

Comment: @ahmd0 No problem! It's worth pointing out that the `HashSet` option uses LINQ as well, just a different syntax of it.

Comment: Not the one I called Method 2 in my OP.

Answer (score 2):

Method 2, using `.ContainsKey`, is more *semantic* and, most likely, more efficient than suppressing the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Using exceptions to control expected execution flow is generally frowned upon, and catching exceptions is expensive, so I'd opt for v2. If it's really important to you, why not set up a benchmark? I'm guessing 2 is "more efficient", but you could easily confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any use of the values in the dictionary, you can use a `HashSet<string>` instead, and adding items to a hash set automatically removes duplicates:

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(
  str.Split(',')
  .Select(s => s.Trim())
  .Where(s => s.Length > 0)
);
```

Comment: @ahmd0: Yes, he added an example at the same time I posted my answer.